# Png signature reading fail

Tags: c++, image, png

I am trying to read the signature of png image file using `std::ifstream` opened it in binary mode but I got only few bytes correct. Surely using png image for input.
Just I want to validate my png image, whats going wrong here.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const auto PNG_SIGN_SIZE = 8;
const uint8_t PNG_SIGN_BUFFER[] = {137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10};

bool validate(const string& filename) {
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(filename, ios::binary);
    bool is_valid = true;

    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        uint8_t buffer[PNG_SIGN_SIZE]{};

        for (int i = 0; i < PNG_SIGN_SIZE; ++i) {
            ifs >> buffer[i];

            if (ifs.fail()) {
                printf("ERROR: Fail to read bytes.\n");
                is_valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < PNG_SIGN_SIZE; ++i) {
            // printf("%u %u\n", buffer[i], PNG_SIGN_BUFFER[i]);
            if (buffer[i] != PNG_SIGN_BUFFER[i]) {
                is_valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    } else {
        printf("ERROR: Could not read <%s>.\n", filename.c_str());
        is_valid = false;
    }

    ifs.close();
    return is_valid;
}

int main() {
    string filename = "baby.png";
    auto res = validate(filename);

    cout << boolalpha << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A png file is binary. Use `ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), sizeof(buffer));` instead of formatted input which is used to read text.

Comment: `ifs >> buffer[i];` with `uint8_t` tells the compiler to read into a character array. It's expecting plain text, and in older C++ Standards, will gleefully run off the end of the array looking for a null terminator.

Comment: Opening in binary mode (which you should do) does not turn `ifs >>` into a binary read, it's still reading text. For a binary read use `ifs.read(...)`.

Comment: @john Thank you, It works. ```ifs.read((char*)buffer, PNG_SIGN_SIZE);```